# Is it possible to select an object in the 3D view, and see it highlighted in the outline view if it is inside a collection?

Tags: outliner

When I select an object in 3D view, how can I see the object highlighted in the Outliner if I have placed the object in a Collection?

[image: grab]

Comment: Hover the mouse over the outliner and press the period ('.') key on the numpad.

Comment: @JohnEason I think you should add your comment as an answer here as well - because these are all answers with useful tips how to find out where the object is, and yours is good when you want to get directly to the object in the outliner so I think there should be a chance to accept this. So I guess Tom has to choose which answer is best for what he wants to get or what is the easiest, most efficient or sufficient for him.

Comment: I agree - this comment fixed the issue for me! Thanks all

Comment: @Gordon Brinkman Now added as an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hover the mouse pointer over the outliner and press <kbd>.</kbd> (period key) on the numpad.

Comment: I forgot to mention that it works the other way round too! If you hilight an object in the Outliner and press period on the numpad while hovering over the 3D view, the view zooms to and centres on the selected object which is very useful.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable showing collections in the outliner by using the collections filter :

[image]

You can have 2 instances of the outliner showing different filtering options if you'd like to :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your object is represented by that upside-down delta (triangle) shape. See how it's highlighted with a light grey box? That's it.

Everything inside a collapsed collection is represented by icons next to its name - meshes with this triangle; cameras, lights, etc. have their own symbols which are colour-coded too. If one of them is selected, you get the little grey box around its icon.

Answer (score 2):

Under Object Properties-collections-it shows you which collection it is in, even if it is hidden in the outliner.

[image]